# About Durrett probability exercise 2.7.5 , does average of centered variable converge to 0 in probability?

Tags: probability-theory

I know [Durrett, probability theory and examples exercise 2.7,5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278016/durrett-probability-theory-and-examples-exercise-2-7-5) exists, but the chosen answer seems faulty to me. Let me know if I mistook it and it is actually right, or please give me some hint if the chosen answer indeed has some logic holes.

The problem is analogous of Cramer's theorem of large deviations, but for infinite moment generating function:

Suppose $\mathbb{E}X_n = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}e^{\theta X} = \infty$ for all $\theta > 0$. ($X_i$ being iid was likely omitted) Then,
$$(1/n) \log P(S_n \geq na) \rightarrow 0$$
holds for $a > 0$.

Specifically, the chosen answer mentions $S_n/(n-1) \rightarrow 0$ in probability because $X_i$ are centered. Strong/Weak law of large numbers were only applicable when $\mathbb{E}|X_i|$ or $Var X_i$ is bounded, and this is likely not the case here. Am I missing something, or is the answer indeed faulty?

I also wonder if there are other ways to tact this problem. In the lecture, we learned about "tilting measure technique" where one adjusts the mean to be e.g. $a$. Could this be applied in the problem?

Comment: I assumed that the $X_i$ have the same distribution (but this assumption was not clearly stated). Otherwise, I think that we can play with weighted sums to build a counter-example.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Still, we need $E|X_i|$ or the like to be bounded for law of large numbers to hold. We do not have that condition here, so I do not get how $S_n / (n-1)$ would be going to 0.

Comment: I know, I implicitely also interpretated $E[X_i]=0$ as the expectation of $\lvert X_i\rvert$ exists and $E[X_i]=0$. I do not have the book of Durrett so I cannot check whether the assumption of identical distribution was made.

Comment: I see. Sadly, I cannot find any assumption like $E|X_i| < \infty$ in the problem, and Durrett book seem to keep notion of $EX_i = 0$ and $E|X_i| < \infty$ separate. so I cannot use SLL here. Are there other ways to prove this?

Comment: If $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|] = \infty$ then we need $\mathbb{E}[(X_i)^+] < \infty$ or $\mathbb{E}[(X_i)^-] < \infty$ for $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ to be well-defined.  The fact that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$ is an assumption implies that $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ is well-defined, and we can't have only the positive part or only the negative part have infinite expected value if $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$.

Comment: Ouch, I missed that one! Admittedly, I have hard time going back and forth with integral and expectation..